# XSL-FO Multiple Page Sequences

Tags: java, xml, applet, xsl-fo, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to implement the example: http://www.scriptorium.com/whitepapers/xslfo/xslfo_4.html - Creating Multiple Page Sequences, for my environment. I get a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when I transform large data.

Here's what part my of my xsl file looks like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:call-template name="LAYOUT"/>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="ROOT/MEM-STMT/COUNTRY ='MU'">  
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pre-print">
          <fo:static-content
              flow-name="xsl-region-before-first">
            <fo:block>
              <xsl:call-template name="HEADER"/>
            </fo:block>
          </fo:static-content>

          <fo:static-content
              flow-name="xsl-region-after">
            <fo:block text-align="center">
              <xsl:call-template name="FOOT"/>
            </fo:block>
          </fo:static-content>

          <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="ROOT/MEM-STMT/FIN-BAL/FIN-BAMT !='0'">
                  <fo:block>
                    <xsl:call-template name="FIN-BAL"/>
                  </fo:block>
                </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="PROVIDER"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="MEM-TOTALS"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="F-OTHER"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="DUE"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="REASON"/>
            </fo:block>
          </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="global">
          <fo:static-content
              flow-name="xsl-region-before-first">
            <fo:block>
              <xsl:call-template name="HEADER"/>
            </fo:block>
          </fo:static-content>

          <fo:static-content
              flow-name="xsl-region-after">
            <fo:block text-align="center">
              <xsl:call-template name="FOOT"/>
            </fo:block>
          </fo:static-content>

          <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="ROOT/MEM-STMT/FIN-BAL/FIN-BAMT !='0'">
                  <fo:block>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="FIN-BAL"/>
                  </fo:block>
                </xsl:when>
              </xsl:choose>    
              <xsl:if test="count(ancestor::PROV)=4">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="PROVIDER"/>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="MEM-TOTALS"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="F-OTHER"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="DUE"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="REASON"/>                                      
            </fo:block>
          </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence> 
        <xsl:if test="count(ancestor::PROV) &lt; 4">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="PROVIDER" mode="page"/>
        </xsl:if>    
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>              
  </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

The sample xml file looks as follows:

```
<ROOT>
  <MEM-STMT>
    <COUNTRY>co</COUNTRY>
    <CURRENCY>cu</CURRENCY>
    <STMT>
      <ST-NO>1</ST-NO>
      <ST-DATE>21-JUL-11</ST-DATE>
      <CC>21</CC>
      <YY>11</YY>
      <MM>07</MM>
      <DD>21</DD>
    </STMT>
    <MEM-DET>
      <MEM-NO>9</MEM-NO>
      <MEM-PROD-LEV>24</MEM-PROD-LEV>
      <MEM-OPTION>option</MEM-OPTION>
      <MEM-EMP-NO/>
      <MEM-EMP-NAME>name</MEM-EMP-NAME>
    </MEM-DET>
    <MEM-ADDR>
      <MEM-NAME>name</MEM-NAME>
      <MEM-ADDR1>                  Addr1</MEM-ADDR1>
      <MEM-ADDR2>                           Addr2</MEM-ADDR2>
      <MEM-ADDR3>                         Addr3</MEM-ADDR3>
      <MEM-SUB>                            Sub</MEM-SUB>
      <MEM-CITY>                          +2</MEM-CITY>
      <MEM-REG>                   Employer:reg</MEM-REG>
      <MEM-CNTRY/>
      <MEM-PCODE/>
      <MEM-EMPCODE/>
    </MEM-ADDR>
    <ACC>
      <PROV>
        <PR-NO>1</PR-NO>
        <PR-NAME>  pr</PR-NAME>
        <REF-NO>1</REF-NO>
        <CLM>
          <REF>1</REF>
          <CL-DEP-NO>04</CL-DEP-NO>
          <CL-DEP-NAME>dep</CL-DEP-NAME>
          <CL-DOS>10-APR-11</CL-DOS>
          <CC>21</CC>
          <YY>11</YY>
          <MM>04</MM>
          <DD>10</DD>
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>1 </CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>desc </CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>
          <CL-NO>1</CL-NO>
          <CL-LINE>2</CL-LINE>
          <CL-AMT>16.8</CL-AMT>
          <CL-TAR-AMT>16.8</CL-TAR-AMT>
          <CL-PAID-PROV>16.8</CL-PAID-PROV>
          <CL-PAID-MEM>0</CL-PAID-MEM>
          <CL-RSN/>
        </CLM>
        <CLM>
          <REF>1</REF>
          <CL-DEP-NO>04</CL-DEP-NO>
          <CL-DEP-NAME>dep </CL-DEP-NAME>
          <CL-DOS>20-APR-11</CL-DOS>
          <CC>21</CC>
          <YY>11</YY>
          <MM>04</MM>
          <DD>20</DD>
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>1 </CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>desc </CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>
          <CL-NO>1</CL-NO>
          <CL-LINE>2</CL-LINE>
          <CL-AMT>50.4</CL-AMT>
          <CL-TAR-AMT>50.4</CL-TAR-AMT>
          <CL-PAID-PROV>50.4</CL-PAID-PROV>
          <CL-PAID-MEM>0</CL-PAID-MEM>
          <CL-RSN/>
        </CLM>
        <TOTALS>
          <TOT-AMT>67.2</TOT-AMT>
          <TOT-TAR-AMT>67.2</TOT-TAR-AMT>
          <TOT-PAID-PROV>67.2</TOT-PAID-PROV>
          <TOT-PAID-MEM>0</TOT-PAID-MEM>
        </TOTALS>
      </PROV>
      <PROV>
        <PR-NO>2</PR-NO>
        <PR-NAME>  pr</PR-NAME>
        <REF-NO>1</REF-NO>
        <CLM>
          <REF>1</REF>
          <CL-DEP-NO>04</CL-DEP-NO>
          <CL-DEP-NAME>dep</CL-DEP-NAME>
          <CL-DOS>10-APR-11</CL-DOS>
          <CC>21</CC>
          <YY>11</YY>
          <MM>04</MM>
          <DD>10</DD>
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>1</CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>desc </CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>
          <CL-NO>1</CL-NO>
          <CL-LINE>2</CL-LINE>
          <CL-AMT>15</CL-AMT>
          <CL-TAR-AMT>0</CL-TAR-AMT>
          <CL-PAID-PROV>15</CL-PAID-PROV>
          <CL-PAID-MEM>0</CL-PAID-MEM>
          <CL-RSN/>
        </CLM>
        <TOTALS>
          <TOT-AMT>15</TOT-AMT>
          <TOT-TAR-AMT>0</TOT-TAR-AMT>
          <TOT-PAID-PROV>15</TOT-PAID-PROV>
          <TOT-PAID-MEM>0</TOT-PAID-MEM>
        </TOTALS>
      </PROV>
      <PROV>
        <PR-NO>1</PR-NO>
        <PR-NAME>  pr</PR-NAME>
        <REF-NO>I0428202</REF-NO>
        <CLM>
          <REF>I0428202</REF>
          <CL-DEP-NO>03</CL-DEP-NO>
          <CL-DEP-NAME>dep</CL-DEP-NAME>
          <CL-DOS>10-APR-11</CL-DOS>
          <CC>21</CC>
          <YY>11</YY>
          <MM>04</MM>
          <DD>10</DD>
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>2</CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>desc</CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>
          <CL-NO>112153</CL-NO>
          <CL-LINE>217615</CL-LINE>
          <CL-AMT>31.58</CL-AMT>
          <CL-TAR-AMT>0</CL-TAR-AMT>
          <CL-PAID-PROV>31.58</CL-PAID-PROV>
          <CL-PAID-MEM>0</CL-PAID-MEM>
          <CL-RSN/>
        </CLM>
        <TOTALS>
          <TOT-AMT>31.58</TOT-AMT>
          <TOT-TAR-AMT>0</TOT-TAR-AMT>
          <TOT-PAID-PROV>31.58</TOT-PAID-PROV>
          <TOT-PAID-MEM>0</TOT-PAID-MEM>
        </TOTALS>
      </PROV>
      <PROV>
        <PR-NO>1</PR-NO>
        <PR-NAME> pr</PR-NAME>
        <REF-NO>0027579</REF-NO>
        <CLM>
          <REF>1</REF>
          <CL-DEP-NO>04</CL-DEP-NO>
          <CL-DEP-NAME>dep</CL-DEP-NAME>
          <CL-DOS>09-JUN-11</CL-DOS>
          <CC>21</CC>
          <YY>11</YY>
          <MM>06</MM>
          <DD>09</DD>
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>99200 </CL-TAR-DRUG-CD>
          <CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>desc</CL-TAR-DRUG-DESC>
          <CL-NO>1</CL-NO>
          <CL-LINE>1</CL-LINE>
          <CL-AMT>12</CL-AMT>
          <CL-TAR-AMT>0</CL-TAR-AMT>
          <CL-PAID-PROV>12</CL-PAID-PROV>
          <CL-PAID-MEM>0</CL-PAID-MEM>
          <CL-RSN/>
        </CLM>
        <TOTALS>
          <TOT-AMT>12</TOT-AMT>
          <TOT-TAR-AMT>0</TOT-TAR-AMT>
          <TOT-PAID-PROV>12</TOT-PAID-PROV>
          <TOT-PAID-MEM>0</TOT-PAID-MEM>
        </TOTALS>
      </PROV>
    </ACC>
    <RSN-LIST>
      <RSN-ERR>????</RSN-ERR>
      <RSN-DESC/>
    </RSN-LIST>
    <FIN-OTHER>
      <FIN-DATE/>
      <FIN-AMT>0</FIN-AMT>
      <FIN-TT/>
    </FIN-OTHER>
    <GTOTALS>
      <GTOT-AMT>125.78</GTOT-AMT>
      <GTOT-TAR-AMT>67.2</GTOT-TAR-AMT>
      <GTOT-PAID-PROV>125.78</GTOT-PAID-PROV>
      <GTOT-PAID-MEM>0</GTOT-PAID-MEM>
    </GTOTALS>
    <MEM-GTOT>
      <M-MESSAGE/>
      <M-TOT-PAID-MEM>0</M-TOT-PAID-MEM>
      <M-PMT-METH/>
    </MEM-GTOT>
    <FIN-BAL>
      <FIN-BDATE>21-JUL-11</FIN-BDATE>
      <FIN-BAMT>0</FIN-BAMT>
      <FIN-BTT/>
    </FIN-BAL>
  </MEM-STMT>
</ROOT>
```

The transformation works but only creates a one page document. I obviously need this transformation to create the entire document.

Comment: Why is the question tagged with [applet]?

Comment: Have you tried allocating more memory to java? (`-Xms`/`-Xmx` on the command line)

Comment: @mzjn, it's tagged with applet because I'm running the transformation code in a JApplett

Comment: @DevNull, I have increased -Xms/-Xmx & java_arguments to max. 2G with no change.

Comment: @Kamza: Have you run the XSLT transformation and XSL-FO rendering from the command line to see if that makes any difference?

Comment: @mzjn, thanks for the response. When I run  _XSLT transformation and XSL-FO rendering from the command line_ the resultant document gets created with all the pages - no problem...

Comment: @mzjn, just to add. When I run the transformation on command prompt I use the xsl file without the two xsl:if statements effectively fitting all the content in one page sequence - & the process runs successfully (no memory error) & creates pdf as desired.